# KDE black screen after opening lid

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 23.04

I get a black screen when I open my laptop lid, and I have to reboot the system by pressing boot button. The last time I was trying start plasma (in tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3)

```
kstart5 plasmashell
```

and there was additional output information that may help.

kstart5 output:

[image: kstart5_output]

It says about Qt platform plugin 'xcb' that could not be loaded even it was found, and reinstalling the application may fix the problem.

My plasma version is 5.27.4.

Other system information:

[image: here]

The black screen does not appear every time I open the lid but about once a week.

Comment: Looks like there was issue related to connecting external monitor.
In the office i use external monitor to work with two displays. After i changed "bad" external monitor to another one, the problem is gone.